# Sort data based on another column

Tags: excel

Given the following table

```
   A       B     C        D
   fred    1     wilma    6
   wilma   6     fred     1
   barney  3     bill     4
   bill    4     steve    6
   bob     5     george   7
                 barney   3
                 bob      5
```

Is it possible to sort C and D to match the arrangement in A and B without sorting A and B?

Comment: Can you show what the result should look like?  If you mean that the numbers in D should be sorted in the same order as B, you could add a column E `=MATCH(D1,B:B,0)` (in E1 and drag down) and sort C:E by column E.

Comment: The result should look like column A B with the extras in no specific order down the bottom

Comment: Will `C` *always* contain *every* person in `A`? Because then just make column E a `vlookup` from A (i.e. `vlookup(C1, A:B, 2 0)`) and sort but column `E`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in E1, and drag down: `=MATCH(C1,A:A,0)` (1,2 in screenshot below)

Then select columns C, D, and E, and sort by column E. (3,4,5)

[image]